# Angular Observable don't set local variable while calling API

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I'm trying to set value in a local variable like this:

```
export class memberComponent implements OnInit {

   member : Member = new Member();
   constructor(private memberService: MemberService) {}

   ngOnInit() {
     this.loadMember();
     console.log("member 1: ", this.member); // in here member is empty
   }

   loadMember(){
     this.memberService.getMember("john").subscribe(mem => {
       this.member = mem;
       console.log("member 2: ", this.member);// in here member is NOT empty
     });
   }
}
```

And because the `member` is empty nothing shows in the page. Here is my component.html

```
<h1>{{member.userName}}</h1>
```

Finally, this is the memberService:

```
export class MemberService {

  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getMember(userName: string) {
    return  this.http.get<Member>(this.baseUrl + 'users/' + userName);
  }

}
```

I tried to user `pipe(take(1))` method and `interface` instead of `class` but there were no difference. And nothing has shown in my html page.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: can you show me the response of getMember method please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be receiving a can't read userName of undefined error in browser console. to fix this try use elvis operator like below :-

```
<h1>{{member?.userName}}</h1>
```

Comment: Actually, I had `?` in my real code and without it I get the error that you said. But still there is no data to show in HTML page.

Comment: can you provide data of member thats printing in console?

Comment: That specific field was empty. :)

Comment: can you please mark this as answer if it helped.